# Finding field containing maximum value for each row in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, maximum

I have a table with the number of buildings constructed per time period in each district, and I would like to determine the time period in which most buildings were built.

For example, for the following table, I'd like to get create a field containing `"1971_2000"`.

| District name | 1945_1970 | 1971_2000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| District 1 | 2 | 5 |

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and expressions. In this solution it is only necessary to write which fields are not to be considered in the calculation, all the other fields are taken automatically:

```
with_variable('sel',
        array_filter(
                map_avals(attributes()), @element not in ("District_name")
                ),
        map_akeys(attributes())[array_find(@sel, array_max(@sel))]
        )
```

[image]

---

**References:**

- Italian: https://hfcqgis.opendatasicilia.it/esempi/maxValoreCampoNome/

Answer (score 3):

Use this expression in the Field Calculator and change field names (if necessary, here on lines 4-5, you can add more lines if you have more fields with the same pattern):

```
with_variable(
    'map',
    map(
        '1945_1970',"1945_1970",
        '1971_2000',"1971_2000"
    ),
    array_get(
        map_akeys(@map),
        array_find(
            map_avals(@map),
            array_max(map_avals(@map))
        )
    )
)
```

[image]